# How to add or subtract from a property value in SoapUI using Groovy

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui, assertions

In SoapUI, I am grabbing a testcase property that displays the value as 47.79.

```
def test= messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue('test')
```

I want to grab this variable value and create two new variables. One will add up to a pence so that the value would be 47.80, and another that will subtract a pence so that it's 47.78.

I am unsure how to implement this in groovy as they tend to append at the end or give me error. How is it written in groovy to do the above?

Below is my attempt:

```
def testUp= Double.Parse(test) + 0.01
def testDown= Double.Parse(test) - 0.01
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "they tend to append at the end or give me error"?

Comment: Merlin, can you check the below solution and see if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there a test case level property, say, `test` is defined with value `47.79` as stated in the question.

The mistake in your script is `Double.Parse()`

Here is the script it can do what you are looking for:

```
//Get property value and convert it as Double
def testValue = context.expand('${#TestCase#test}') as Double

//Add and subtract with new variables.
def testUp = testValue + 0.01
def testDown = testValue - 0.01

//Check if the values are correct, of course, value may vary based on the data.
assert 47.80 == testUp
assert 47.78 == testDown
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct function name is : Double.parseDouble(test)

```
def test= messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue('test')

    def testUp= Double.parseDouble(test) + 0.01


    log.info testUp
    log.info testUp.getClass()
```